# Deploying a website and a system

Tags: php, mysql, web, dns, filezilla

Good day.

I' have a thesis. It is composed of a website, php based and a system which is vb.net. My website's database (mysql) is connected to the system. I test my system and it is working properly.

My problem is how am I gonna deploy my website to the internet and somehow, also connected to the system I created. I'm going to host the website because it's for a short time only.

I'm going to buy a domain at godaddy.com. My laptop will be the host for the both website and system.

Can i use filezilla? Is my logic possible?

Sorry for the wrong grammar or bad logic. I'm a student and a beginner. Hope you understand. Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you looking for a free host? http://www.byethost.com/ provides free hosting for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this, but the site will only be available if and when your laptop is online and connected to a known, **static** IP address, because you'll have to configure the DNS servers at GoDaddy to point to that IP address.

You may need to purchase a hosting package with MySQL, and put your database and application up there. You can update the site with Filezilla, yes.

Comment: Are there any webhosting packages that accepts both website and a system? It is because as a student, I really don't have a big budget for deploying my thesis. Thank you.

Comment: @Gerald You can certainly run web *applications*. Beyond that, I'm not sure what packages are going to be available to you.